# Закрытие консольного приложения .NET по ESC

Tags: c#, .net, консоль

Как закрыть консольное приложение C# кнопкой <kbd>ESC</kbd>?

Answer (score 2):

Например так:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Press Esc to exit");
        do
        {
            // ваши действия
        } while (Console.ReadKey().Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ну, что-то подобное:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{           
   Form1 fm = new Form1();
   System.Threading.Thread formShower = new System.Threading.Thread(ShowForm);
   formShower.Start(fm);
   if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
   {
        Process.GetCurrentProcess().Kill();
   }
}

private static void ShowForm(object formObject)
{
    Form1 form = formObject as Form1;
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/609795/why-shouldnt-i-use-process-getcurrentprocess-kill-to-exit-my-winform-applic

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string text; 
    Console.WriteLine("Напишите что то");                
    Console.WriteLine("или нажмите Esc что бы выйти");
    text = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(text);
    switch (Console.ReadKey().Key)
    {
        case ConsoleKey.Escape:
            Environment.Exit(0);
            break;
    }

 }
```