Как выйти из консольного приложения по ESC во время ввода текста через ReadLine()?
Как организовать выход из приложения по нажатию клавиши esc? Например, чтобы в данном методе не нужно было дважды прописывать условия для выхода
public static void LoginWrong(string username, string password)
{ 
    while (Login(username, password) == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Имя пользователя или пароль введены неверно. Попробуйте еще раз. Чтобы выйти из приложений, нажмите клавишу Esc");
        Console.WriteLine("введите имя пользователя:");
      
        username = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("введите пароль:");
       
        password = Console.ReadLine();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Авторизация прошла успешно");
}


https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/251154/220553

var key = Console.ReadKey(true);
if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}


Во-первых, это нужно написать как минимум два раза
Во-вторых, если использовать ReadKey, то в консоли не будет отображаться первый введенный символ с клавиатуры

вот тут предлагается замена функции ReadLine (ее доработать придется под ваши требования)
